# docker e angular cirando comunicação com api

Tags: angular, docker, redes

Começei a usar o docker a pouco tempo, tentei o deploy de duas aplicações  o frontend em angular e uma api em python, problema que mesmo na mesma network no docker eu só consigo acessar a api com o ip externo do Container o interno apresenta o erro abaixo, queria que so o host do container do front ficasse exposto no final e a comunicação ficasse totalmente interna entre os 2 containers

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - devtest

  frontend: 
    container_name: frontend 
    build: ./ProjectCremona 
    volumes: # Volume binding
      - './ProjectCremona:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    networks:
      - devtest

    command: >
      bash -c "npm install && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"

networks:
    devtest:
      driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer fazer não é possível.

Quando você acessa a sua aplicação, ela está rodando no seu Browser (Fora da rede do docker). Por isso não funciona..

Para que isso fosse viável, você teria que rodar o browser dentro do docker também.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o service discovery que o docker possui, você não precisaria expor a porta do backend, basta coloca na url de comunicação: nome_do_servico:porta_do_serviço, no seu caso, colocar na url: http://backend:80.
Remova o ports do backend e utilize o link também no seu docker-compose.